# Ionic background task at a specific time?

Tags: typescript, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

Is there anyway I can start a background task in Ionic 3 mobile app at a specific time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this plugin to achieve this..

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode/

I hope it will work.

Comment: I was able to do a workaround using this plugin. thanks :)

Comment: @Mu'menTayyem Hi, I'm in a similar situation, would really like to know how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage local notifications plugin for that:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/

Good guidancce here by Josh:
https://www.joshmorony.com/getting-familiar-with-local-notifications-in-ionic-2/